# Phonegap native iOS7 blur effect

Tags: javascript, css, cordova

Is there a more native solution using Phonegap to create the iOS7 blur effect other than using CSS or javascript?

I have never used Phonegap before, my app needs the blur effect and I'm trying to decide to either use my web skills to create this app or hire a native developer.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, as usual, *it depends*.

CSS3 does support blur, but not in the same way iOS 7 uses. This means it is possible to create a *static* blur (say, on the navigation bar), but there is no great way discovered (last I knew) to enable a *dynamic* blur -- which is probably what you want, if trying to mimic iOS 7.

Although it flies a bit in the face of the question to pose this as a solution, one option is to simply *not implement a blur*. You can approximate something similar by using a gradient (say, 75% opaque to 100% opaque). Depending on your needs, this may be sufficient. (I first noticed this at this site: https://mir.aculo.us/2013/09/16/how-to-create-a-web-app-that-looks-like-a-ios7-native-app-part-1/)

The other option is to use a native navigation bar. It introduces its own set of problems (for example: how best to synchronize your non-native view transitions with native navigation bar's transitions), *but* it means you also get iOS 7's blurring on the navigation bar for free. I've got a (very alpha) plugin that implements this (as well as toolbars) here: http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.photokandy.nativecontrols

Comment: Thank you for your answer Kerri, this supports my fears. Is there any way that you know to take a snapshot of the page with Javascript? That way I can put it over the content, blur it, then put the transparent element on top of it.

Comment: There are, but none that work performantly (or at all) on mobile browsers *that I know of*. For now, we'll just have to wait, approximate, or use native controls for those portions we need blurred.